# Magento - AJAX GetBlock Checkout Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layout, ajax

I'm trying to reload the cart page with AJAX. I'd like to send a "checkout.cart" block via JSON to replace in AJAX call. 
In my controller (I overrided CartController.php), I'm trying to call the line:

```
$checkout_page = $layout->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart')->toHtml();
$response['checkout_block'] = $checkout_page;
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

But a error happen

Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in C:\D\Websites\magento\app\code\local\Excellence\Ajax\controllers\IndexController.php on line 211

Answer (score 1):

if your action which will reload "checkout.cart" in Excellence\Ajax\controllers\IndexController.php named: reloadCart()

you go to checkout.xml and update like this:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    ....
</checkout_cart_index>

<ajax_index_reloadcart>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_index"/>
</ajax_index_reloadcart>
```

then it will works.

ref: http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/mage_checkout_cartcontroller-class-getblock-8217-8217-checkoutcart-8217-8217-is-false-solved-nbsp--60544.html